# XSLT Levels in source file but no levels in destination file

Tags: xslt

I have input fil as shown on the picture, and I want an output like shown on the picture to.
My problem is how to control the list-levels, because the output file has only one level, so if anyone have an idea I will be very happy
The source file can have more than 2 levels.
Input:

```
xml version="1.0"?>
<Index>
<Indentatio>
<Explicatus>1)</Explicatus>
<Char>1)on Level 1</Char>
</Indentatio>
<Index>
<Indentatio>
<Explicatus>a)</Explicatus>
<Char> a) on level 2</Char>
</Indentatio>
<Indentatio>
<Explicatus>b)</Explicatus>
<Char> b) on level 2</Char>
</Indentatio>
</Index>
<Indentatio>
<Explicatus>2)</Explicatus>
<Char>1)on Level 1</Char>v
</Indentatio>
</Index>
```

Output:

```
<List>
<ListItem Level="1" Class="1">
1) on level 1
1) on level 1
</ListItem>
<ListItem Level="2" Class="1">
<ID>a)</ID>
a) on level 2
</ListItem>
<ListItem Level="2" Class="1">
<ID>b)</ID>
b) on level 2
</ListItem>
<ListItem Level="1" Class="1">
<ID>2)</ID>
2) on level 1
</ListItem>
</List>
```

Comment: I can't see any picture.  But you shouldn't post your input and output as pictures, instead include the XML _as text_ so we can copy and paste it, and also include the XSLT you've tried so far.  Please edit the question to include these details.

Comment: I do not know what happened to the pictures, but here is the code.

Comment: I don't think your output matches the input. If it does, you need to explain how.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <List>
        <xsl:for-each select="//Indentatio">
            <ListItem Level="{count(ancestor::Index)}" Class="1">
                <ID><xsl:value-of select="Explicatus"/></ID>
                <xsl:value-of select="Char"/>
            </ListItem>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </List> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, this will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<List>
   <ListItem Level="1" Class="1">
      <ID>1)</ID>1)on Level 1</ListItem>
   <ListItem Level="2" Class="1">
      <ID>a)</ID> a) on level 2</ListItem>
   <ListItem Level="2" Class="1">
      <ID>b)</ID> b) on level 2</ListItem>
   <ListItem Level="1" Class="1">
      <ID>2)</ID>1)on Level 1</ListItem>
</List>
```

Note that outputting mixed content is rarely a good idea.

Comment: It was exactly what I was looking for, very nice solution, thanks a lot.
The problem is, I got the data according to the Input-file from one system, and must deliver data to another system according to a schema used in the output-file.